# My guard-livereload is not working, please advise how to fix this

Tags: rubygems, guard

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04

I've installed **guard-livereload**, I tried to config **/var/www/bootstrap/Guardfile** as follow

```
# A sample Guardfile
# More info at https://github.com/guard/guard#readme

guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{.+\.(html|php)$})
end
```

I can start guard at my project folder and when open the browser with livereload extension installed I got a **"Browser connected"** message at the terminal.

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, after saving the .html file, there is no update at the browser and there is nothing notify at the terminal.

Please advise, what to do to fix this.

P.S. Do I need **Gemfile** for this, if so where to save Gemfile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux and Sublime Text 3 you need to set 'atomic save' to false. Ie, add the following to your user preferences:

```
"atomic_save": false
```

If that doesn't work, you can also run 'bundle exec guard --debug' to see at exactly which step things aren't working.